# How to get all items in ListItemCollection when using an AppOnlyAuthenticatedContext

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to use an AppOnlyAuthenticated context in order to loop over all the documents in a specific list in Sharepoint. The reason to use the AppContext is that this needs to be automated (part of a script) and using an actual user accounts seems like the wrong choice.

Repro:

```
// using OfficeDevPnp.Core;
// using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
var webUrl = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/test";
var appId = "xXXXX-xxxx-.....";
var appSecret = "longSecret";
var listTitle = "ListTitle";
var am = new AuthenticationManager();
using (var context = am.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(webUrl, appId, appSecret))
{
    var lists = context.Web.Lists;
    var list = lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var listItems = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(rowLimit = 5));
    
    context.Load(lists);
    context.Load(list);
    context.Load(listItems, items => item.Include(i => i.Id));
    
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    
    var list_ItemCount = list.ItemCount;
    var listItems_Count = listItems.Count;
}
```

}

The `list_ItemCount` has the correct value of items in that list of files but `listItems_Count` is zero. Obviously, when trying to loop over `listItems`, there is nothing to enumerate.

Could it be a permission thing? Or is something else causing the issue?